# Reactjs url path issue

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a running webserver which all the http endpoints are running with the following base url:

```
http://<some_name>/widget/
```

Also, I have a reactjs app in the frontend. The problem is after building reactjs app, in the built `index.html` it uses the following url to load js files:

```
http://<some_name>/
```

Is there any way to tell reactjs to load js files from correct path or any other ways?

Comment: Are you using a custom build setup or something like `create-react-app` to generate a production build?

Answer (score 0):

This can be configured in your config, whether in a json, yml or other. Simply search your project for the url it's now rendering on and add to the url (in both dev & production/live config)

I'll show a little example here:

```
"Cors": {
   "AllowedOrigins": [ "http://localhost:3000" ]
},
```

This is my dev config for local. What you want to do is add widget behind your url like so:

```
"Cors": {
   "AllowedOrigins": [ "http://localhost:3000/widget" ]
},
```